# Vlookup using Regex Extract - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I trying to do insert an image into a cell in google sheets.
I'm using vlookup and regex extract to lookup columns to retrieve the image URL for the IMAGE function in google sheets.

However one of the lookup columns has the lookup value (SKU) but in a string.

When the string ends with the lookup value (SKU) it works, when it starts with the lookup value (SKU) it does'nt work.

I have shared the [sheet with examples where it works and where it doesn't.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Wk0CKqcuwAhxtZhNd4eokwNXGdJhSWzeKGsHQcKJKVQ/edit#gid=0)

I'd like it to work regardless of where the lookup value is (SKU) in the string even it the string has special characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fetch you two more images and I doubt you need to cater for where the SKU is at the end of the string:

```
=image(iferror(vlookup(A2&"*",Sheet2!A:B,2,0),vlookup("*"&A2&"*",Sheet2!A:B,2,0)),1)
```

For `GK0095` I think you have an unrelated issue.

Comment: Thank you very much, that seems to have solved the problem, GK0095 didn't work cause of an issue with the URL itself.